# how to get nice alt+tab effect on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Jaunty (9.04).  the alt+tab effect looks very bad.  Is there a way to change the alt+tab effect? maybe make it look more like a mac?

Comment: Are you running Compiz?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "bad"?

Answer (score 3):

You want to install Compiz.

First enable proprietary drivers;

Go to System > Administration > Hardware Drivers, then click "Activate" for any drives provided.

You can then follow the Ubuntu.com compiz guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager/CompizFusion).

Use ccsm (as shown in the guide) to change all manner of compiz settings, including the alt-tab decorator.